# return dynamically generated value from function

Tags: gcc, types, gcc-warning

Due to misconception of gcc memory allocation I have questions regarding once the variable types and secondly a question about returning dynamically changing values from a function.

1. Is there a function from which i could analyze the type of a variable. (I have compiler warnings which tell me about wrong type usage. So type-analyzing occurs through out compilation.)
2. How would I make a function which gives me back the value the function just generated?
   For instance I have function and main part where I call the function. Just the call of the function should give me the value it is operating one:

   ```
         int func(){
           for(i; 0 to 256;i++){
            return i; }
           }
           main(){
           for(j; 0 to 256;j++){
           func(); // should give me back the current value of i - e.g. for i = 3 -> j = 3
             }
           }
   ```

This makes me also question when do I actually should use either function arguments or rather a return value for giving me back some value. (What's the return value restricted to as a type?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Certainly the gcc compiler warnings already name the involved type(s).
2. Possibly you mean something like that: `int func() { static int i; return i++; }`

> What's the return value restricted to as a type?

**ISO/IEC 9899:201x**, **6.9.1 Function definitions**, **Constraints**

> 3 The return type of a function shall be void or a complete object
>   type other than array type.